# JOIN statement to obtain MAX value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (`user` and `I_S`) and the `I_S` table contains a column called `score`. I need to obtain the highest score and the corresponding user name from the tables.

I used a left join but I keep getting an error saying

> Unknown column 'I_S.total_score' in 'field list'

This is the query I used.

```
SELECT MAX(interview_sessions.total_score) 
FROM interview_sessions as sc 
LEFT JOIN user as u on sc.user_id = u.user_id
```

Comment: This makes no sense, the query should probably be `SELECT u.user_name, MAX(sc.total_score) FROM ... GROUP BY u.user_name` with posted elements but that doesn't explain the error message about `I_S.total_score`

Comment: plz mention user and interview_sessions table structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.name, I_S.score FROM users 
LEFT JOIN I_S ON I_S.user_id = users.user_id WHERE score IN (SELECT MAX(score) FROM I_S)
```

All users with Max score.

And i think you should write sc.total_score instead interview_sessions.total_score in your query because you use alias

Comment: An edited version of this worked. Thank you @Vlad Latish

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
SELECT MAX(sc.total_score) 
FROM interview_sessions as sc 
LEFT JOIN user as u on sc.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an inner query to first determine WHAT is the highest score.  Form that, re-join to the interview sessions table on THAT max score.  Then join to users to get the names.  It is possible multiple people can have a same max score.

```
select
   from
      ( SELECT MAX(i_s.total_score) as MaxScore
           from interview_sessions i_s ) maxAll
      JOIN interview_sessions i_s2
         on maxAll.MaxScore = i_s2.total_score
         JOIN User u
            on i_s2.user_id = u.user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
select b.*,a.totalscore  from user b
inner join( select userid,max(total_score) as totalscore from I_S) a on a.userid=b.userid
```